# Cheapest place to park for two weeks while working in Boston?

Tags: automobiles, boston

Where is a good place that I can park my car for two weeks while I work in Boston?

The hotel that I'm staying at charges an absurd 40 dollars a day. Plus, it looks like it would be a mess trying to drive into downtown.

I've read online that the Economy parking at the airport is a good one. I was also thinking maybe one of the subway terminals outside of the city may be cheaper.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should look around http://www.mbta.com/index.asp end point maps.  May be cheaper to buy a 2 weeks worth of rail tickets and live outside downtown.  Or just don't take your car with you and Uber it.

Comment: Isn't there free parking on streets outside the center?

Comment: Do you intend to abandon your car for those 2 weeks, or use it every day?

Comment: @JonathanReez - sure, but if you simply drop your car on a side street for two weeks, it's likely to be reported as abandoned and then towed. Out-of-state plates may actually make that _less_ likely, as residents might assume someone visiting a neighbor, but I wouldn't want to rely on that.

Comment: @JonathanReez: pretty much everything within subway range requires a "resident permit" for street parking. It's free but you need a resident sticker or visitor tag.

Comment: Street parking might be a hassle due to street sweeping.  In the 2000 it was a $75 ticket probably more now.

Answer (score 5):

That depends a bit how often you want to access the car. For example the Framingham Logan Express offers parking at $7/night. With bus fares that would be about $125 but it takes about an hour for inbound and outbound travel

Overnight parking is available at some of the MBTA lots (see http://www.mbta.com/riding_the_t/parking/default.asp?id=25204) and you could just take a train or subway from there, but that's probably not cheaper.

Comment: I think it's likely that the OP doesn't need access to their car during the visit, so no need to commute back and forward to Framingham

Comment: Good idea, and it's worth noting that there are Logan Express lots in multiple outlying suburbs, so depending on where the OP stays another might be more convenient (Woburn also offers a commuter train): https://www.massport.com/logan-airport/to-and-from-logan/logan-express/

Answer (score 1):

Economy parking at the airport [would cost you $260 for 14 days](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/parking-information/where-to-parkrates/) and this seems to be the cheapest option around.

To confirm this, you could [use this price checker,](http://boston.bestparking.com/) and enter the dates you are looking for.

Some hotels may let you park your car while you are working, [as stated here](http://airportparkinghelper.com/cheap-boston-logan-airport-parking-rates-bos-long-term/)

Answer (score 1):

What about taking a rental car to Boston?  Drive the car there, check in, and then return the car.  When your done working pick up a car, and head home.

Rental cars are expensive now, but I would hope that 2 days worth of rentals wouldn't cost more than $560